# How to install cached archives in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, emacs

After I update my Emacs to the newest version(GNU Emacs 24.1.50.1) through [emacs-snapshot PPA](http://emacs.naquadah.org/) :

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

I got an warning when I use rinari to programming Rails project.

I am tired to wait the author to fix this issue. So I decided to 'roll back' my Emacs to the previous version that I installed.

I find the archives in **/var/cache/apt/archives/** directory:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120609-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120614-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120615-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120622-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120629-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot_2%3a20120701-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120609-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120614-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120615-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120622-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120629-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120701-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120609-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120614-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120615-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120622-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120629-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120701-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120609-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120614-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120615-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120622-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120629-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120701-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
```

So, How to install the specified version(old version) of Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the correct release that you know it is working and install it manually. Note that packages are interrelated, so you may need a set of corresponding files, such as:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-common_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-gtk_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/emacs-snapshot-bin-common_2%3a20120608-1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb
```

When you identify the version you need of the package, you just install them with `dpkg`:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i file1.deb file2.deb ...
```

It may tell you're downgrading packages, but you can go ahead. You also can deinstall current emacs snapshot packages.

Another option is just to select which version you want to install from the precise repository, by forcing the version. First, you identify what version you have available in the repos:

```
$ apt-cache show emacs-snapshot
```

This will tell you something like:

```
Package: emacs-snapshot
Priority: optional
Section: editors
Installed-Size: 14390
Version: 2:20120701-1~ppa1~precise1
```

Then, you can force installation of a version with

```
$ sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot=2:20120701-1~ppa1~precise1
```

(the version shown in the available package).

Comment: Awesome! After rollback to version 2:20120622-1~ppa1~precise1, no warnings any more. Thank you very much!